# How to find programmatically what is the root element of the plist

Tags: iphone, plist

How to find out programmatically what's the root element of the plist, i.e whether it is Array or Dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

Load the plist with `+[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:…]`, then check the `-class` of the resulting object.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below:

```
NSData *plistData;  
NSString *error;  
NSPropertyListFormat format;  
id plist;  

NSString *localizedPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"plist"];  
plistData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:localizedPath];   

plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistData mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&format errorDescription:&error];
if([plist isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
     //do some ...
}
if([plist isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
     //do some ...
}
```

[Additional reading](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationSettings/ApplicationSettings.html) from Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s the Core Foundation way:

```
if (CFGetTypeID((CFPropertyListRef)myPropertyList) == CFDictionaryGetTypeID()) {
    // its a dictionary
}
```

Comment: Hi Nikolai,

Thank you very much, this was what i was looking for, as i am calling two functions named getArray and getDictionary which are doing propertyListSerialization, but before calling these function i needed to enquire whether it is Array or Dictionary. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the class method for this. Use NSObject's isKindOfClass: (or isMemberOfClass:) to test if the object's class is [NSArray class] or [NSDictionary class].

see: [+[NSObject class]](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/class)